# Excel formula not calculating automatically unless press enter for some cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula, xlookup

I have over 3000 cells and about 300 cells where the formula is not calculating (some cells have less than 100 character, most have more than 500 characters that are not calculating).

Can someone help me with this one of explain if it is not possible?

Thank you so much!

I am creating a file to capture the local language translation of each sentences from another sheet. I use the Xlookup as some sentences contains more than 500 characters. The problem is there are some cells that are not capturing the translation/ the formula for that cell is not automatically calculating unless i click the cell and press enter.

I already read some possible issue like the automatic calculation should be ticked, highlight all and replace "=" with "=" to recalculate the cells, used VBA code to auto/force calculate, update to text to columns to update the formatting of cells to general and not as "text". All of these are not working as more than 2k of the cells are working but 300 of them needs to be manually recalculated.

Comment: Is it possible that a macro is running, stopping the calculation?

Comment: Yes, I have a vba code to automatically stack the 3 columns into one but it is not connected to the formula i mentioned, is it still possible that it will still affect the calculations?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention having a macro running, you might consider stopping the calculations at the beginning of the macro, and restarting it once your macro has finished, something like:

```
Sub macro()
  Application.Calculation = xlManual ' Turn Automatic Calculations Off
  ...
  Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic ' Turn Automatic Calculations Back On
End Sub
```